# Eclipse Configuration Error

Tags: android, android-emulator

An internal error occurred during: "Launching New_configuration".
Path for project must have only one segment.
What should I do? 
I cannot open my old Android projects anymore because I come out with that error.

Answer (score 0):

Check your "Run Configuration" of your project. See if you have the correct or existing projects in the folders. Whether you have specified your SDK location/ selected an SDK. Or if you have selected an existing AVD.

Comment: thanx so much..
i m new on android .. didn't know when importing a project we need to do some staff on 'Run Configuration' .. really thanx Hend